# Total Expectation problem to solve in 2 ways - regular and by the law of total expectancy

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Im trying to solve the question in the way of total expectancy (meaning $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$).

the question: "A fair cube with 4 sides is thrown twice. each side has a number from 1 to 4. Let's mark **Y - maximum of two results**. Evaluate E(Y) both by regular way and by the law of total expectation."

So I managed to do it by the regular path:

[image]

However, by the law of total expectation I can't figure out how to do that. I found out that if we mark **X - result of first throw** then:

- $P(Y=1|X=1)=P(Y=2|X=1)=P(Y=3|X=1)=P(Y=4|X=1)=\frac{1}{4}$
- $P(Y=1|X=2)=0$, $P(Y=2|X=2)=\frac{1}{2}$, $P(Y=3|X=2)=P(Y=4|X=2)=\frac{1}{4}$
- $P(Y=1|X=3)=P(Y=2|X=3)=0$, $P(Y=3|X=3)=\frac{3}{4}$, $P(Y=4|X=3)=\frac{1}{4}$
- $P(Y=1|X=4)=P(Y=2|X=4)=P(Y=3|X=4)=0$, $P(Y=4|X=4)=1$

so I see that only $Y|X=1$ ~$U[0,4]$ but I can't say anything about distributions $Y|X=2$, $Y|X=3$, $Y|X=4$. thus I can't use the law of total expectation.

Any advice would be appreciated! thanks

Comment: "I can't say anything about distributions $Y|X=2$, $Y|X=3$, $Y|X=4$" ?? You have just completely computed these, no?

Comment: @Did yes, but I'm looking for a short path. it's very cumbersome..

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a shorter path, so the attached below answer is the current answer (consists of two ways of solution).

I would appreciate a lot if someone finds a shorter answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your stumbling point is that you are trying to think about this in terms of what you know about continuous distributions.  I believe that everything you've done so far is correct, other than your statement "$Y|X=1\sim U[0,4]$".

$Y|X$ is discrete and you have written down the distributions explicitly.  Now you can calculate $E[E[Y|X]]$ as:

$$E[E[Y|X]]=\sum_{k=1}^4E[Y|X=k]P(X=k)$$
Where:
$$E[Y|X=k]=\sum_{j=1}^4j\cdot P(Y=j|X=k)$$

Comment: this is exactly what I said I succeed to do.
furthermore, $Y|X=1\sim U[0,4]$ is very correct.
What I was asking if there's a shorter path, that was the original question.

for example, hypothetically,  if $Y|X=1\sim U[0,4]$ and $Y|X=2\sim U[0,4]$ and $Y|X=3\sim U[0,4]$ and $Y|X=4\sim U[0,4]$ then the calculation was much easier - because it's a known distribution with a known expectancy formula.

Comment: No, you calculated: $E[Y] = \sum_{k=1}^4 k\cdot P(Y=k)$

Comment: $Y|X=1\sim U[0,4]$ is unequivocally incorrect in this case.  If $Y|X=1$ were a uniform variable from 0 to 4, then it could take the value 2.999965 for example.  How could that be the maximum value of two rolls of the "4-sided cube" (whatever that is)?

Comment: for example, hypothetically,  if $Y|X=1\sim U[0,4]$ and $Y|X=2\sim U[0,4]$ and $Y|X=3\sim U[0,4]$ and $Y|X=4\sim U[0,4]$ then the calculation was much easier - because it's a known distribution with a known expectancy formula. or if $Y|X\sim HG(4,5-X,1)$ then $E[E[Y|X]]=E[\frac{5-X}{4}]=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{1}{4}E[X]$ - implementation of the law of total expectation.

**BY THE WAY: $Y|X=1\sim U[0,4]$ for uniform *discrete* distribution**

Comment: but because I don't have the distribution of **Y|X** I can't implement the law of total expectation.. thus I asked in this post if there's an option to find this distribution to evaluate all of it in a much shorter way...

Comment: I apologize, it didn't occur to me that you might be talking about a discrete uniform distribution.  If you are looking for a shorter path because the computations are tedious, perhaps it would be a good exercise to try to implement this in your favorite programming language and let the computer do the work.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help. what do you mean to implement it in a programming language? what to implement? in which way the computer can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Who knows if anyone is looking anymore, never mind OP, but this is a concept I'm trying to grasp as well.  I *think* I understand Ami's dissatisfaction with her own solution -- I too started by computing each conditional probability and wondered what I was supposed to have learned -- and so I've come up with my own attempt to sidestep the tedious, point-by-point computation.  So --

We begin with $P(Y = y  | X)$.

$\circ$ If $y < X$, then clearly $P(Y = y  | X)  = 0$.

$\circ$ If $y > X$, then $Y = y$ if and only if the second die yields $y$ -- i.e., precisely when $X_2 = y$.  Hence, $P(Y = y  | X) = 1/4$.

$\circ$ Finally, if $y = X$, then this is because $X_2 \le X$.  There are $X$ ways for this to happen, and so $P(Y = y  | X) = X/4$.

We can condense this as

\begin{align}
P(Y = y  | X) = \frac{1_{\left[ y > X\right]} + X \cdot 1_{\left[ y = X \right]}}{4},
\end{align}

where $1_A$ is the usual indicator function.

This gives us

\begin{align}
E[Y] &= E[E[Y|X]] \\
&= E\left[\sum_{y = 1}^{4} y \cdot \frac{1_{\left[ y > X\right]} + X \cdot 1_{\left[ y = X \right]}}{4} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{4} E\left[\sum_{y = 1}^{4} y \cdot \left( 1_{\left[ y > X\right]} + X \cdot 1_{\left[ y = X \right]} \right) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{x = 1}^4 \frac{1}{4} \left( \sum_{y = 1}^{4} y \cdot \left( 1_{\left[ y > x\right]} + x \cdot 1_{\left[ y = x \right]} \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{16} \left( \sum_{x = 1}^4 \sum_{y = 1}^{4} y \cdot 1_{\left[ y > x\right]}  + \sum_{x = 1}^4 \sum_{y = 1}^{4} yx \cdot 1_{\left[ y = x \right]} \right). \\
\end{align}

Now, the first double summation is the sum of all values of $y$ multiplied by the number of $x$-values that are smaller.  The second is the sum of squares from $1$ to $4$.  Therefore,

\begin{align}
E[Y] &= \frac{1}{16} \left[ \left( 1\cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 2 + 4 \cdot 3 \right) + \left( 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 \right) \right] \\
&= \frac{20 + 30}{16} \; = \; \frac{25}{8} \\
\end{align}

Is this simpler than the brute-force method?  I don't know.  But at least it
generalizes -- with appropriate adjustments to the denominator in the conditional probability -- to dice with any number of sides.